# Help on Recursion theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $H: N$x $N \to N$ be a function and $h_m: N\to N$ be given by $h_m(n)=H(m,n) ,\forall n.$  Show there exists a function $f$ such that for every $m$ there is an $n$ with $f(k)>h_m(k),  \forall k>n$

How do I use Recursion theorem to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(k) = \max\{h_j(k) + 1 : j < k\}$.

For all $m$, if $k > m$, then $f(k) \geq h_m(k) + 1 > h_m(k)$